# How to handle POST request from react to django?

Tags: reactjs, django, post

How to handle a post request?  I don't have any spec about that request. How do I can handle it proper that request and write in to my model?

Answer (score 0):

In the Django view by checking `request.POST` you can check your request is `POST` or not.
For example:

```
def test_view(request):
    if request.POST:
        # Do something for POST requests
```

Also, another way is checking `request.method` parameter.

```
def test_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Do something for POST requests
```